# mysql when in command line how to jump previous line

Tags: mysql, linux, console, command-line

How to jump previous line when in mysql console ?

[image]

i want jump to FROM line ?

Sory for my bad english.

Comment: should be migrated...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.  [3.2. Entering Queries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/entering-queries.html) says your only option is to end the query and [Ctrl]+[C] out.

> At this point, what do you do? The simplest thing is to cancel the
>   command. However, you cannot just type \c in this case, because mysql
>   interprets it as part of the string that it is collecting. Instead,
>   enter the closing quote character (so mysql knows you've finished the
>   string), then type \c:

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but you cant go to previous line you have to start new query if you want to change it.